# What exactly happened to Hendrik Vogt's "mathmode" tag badge?

Tags: support, badges

I'm pretty sure that [Hendrik Vogt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1235/hendrik-vogt) had already earned the [mathmode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/65/mathmode) bronze tag badge (and was the third user to do so after Stefan Kottwitz and TH.). A few days ago, his "mathmode" badge disappeared -- presumably because it was revoked after one of his answers tagged with [mathmode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathmode) was voted down and his upvote/downvote score fell below +100. Since yesterday, Hendrik Vogt's [mathmode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathmode) score is (back) at +100, but his "mathmode" badge hasn't reappeared so far (although new tag badges have been awarded to other users). Please shed some light on the matter.

Comment: Wow, a question with my name in its title! And this with me having been mostly absent in the past weeks. What I can tell you: I'm pretty sure your first sentence is correct, but I didn't receive any downvotes this year. Maybe the tag was removed from a question?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87506/what-happens-to-a-tag-badge-when-a-tag-is-merged-with-another-one-or-it-is-delet

Comment: Might be just a matter of delay. However, it seems already quite long and as pointed out: other people received tag badges as well.

Comment: Just for the record, I've got no idea why, but now the tag badge is back.

Comment: @Hendrik: One question with an answer from you was retagged to {mathmode}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the rules here:

[What are tag badges? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work)

If you hover over his mathmode tag in the user profile you will see:

> "Asked 6 non-wiki questions with a
>   total score of 52. Answered 19
>   non-wiki questions with a total score
>   of 101."

So he is one answer off from the badge.

Tag badges are the only ones that are taken away regularly, by the system, due to people no longer meeting the requirements. My guess is that a retagging happened that caused him to no longer meet the requirements.

Comment: Many thanks -- I wasn't aware that the "visible" answer count (25 in Hendrik's case) included answers to community wiki questions.

Comment: @lockstep: It not an _answer_ count, but a _question and answer_ count, as far as I see.